# jQuery ajax collision issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been coding an ajax request and i have a problem with it.

```
var addonUploadForm = $('#addonUploadForm');

var addonUploadFormMessages = $('#addonUploadForm-messages');

$(addonUploadForm).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //var formData = $(addonUploadForm).serialize();
    //var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    var formData = new FormData($('#addonUploadForm')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(addonUploadForm).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        xhr: function() {  },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false // marked line of error
        success: function(response) {
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).addClass('success');

            $(addonUploadFormMessages).html(response);

            $('#addonTitle').val('');
            $('#addonDescription').val('');
            $('#addonFile').val('');
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).addClass('error');
            grecaptcha.reset();

            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(addonUploadFormMessages).html(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(addonUploadFormMessages).html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in out"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a><strong>Error!</strong> An error occured and your message could not be sent.</div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

That is my code and on the marked line there is a missing , and this code works fine apart from doesnt display the request on the page and it instead just takes me to the ajax url but if i put the , in it does nothing when i submit the form no errors, no nothing.

Comment: You're missing a comma. There's no way this "works".

Comment: it does if you dont believe me sign in using steam [here](https://toybox.rtm516.co.uk/ingame/?show=upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it i had 2 versions of jquery runnning with noconflict and they where 1.11 and 1.4, and 1.4 was last loaded before this. So i had to change my no conflict to `var jq1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);` and then my ajax code to

```
var addonUploadForm = $('#addonUploadForm');

var addonUploadFormMessages = $('#addonUploadForm-messages');

$(addonUploadForm).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('#addonUploadForm')[0]);

    jq1.ajax($(addonUploadForm).attr('action'), {
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(addonUploadForm).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).addClass('success');

            $(addonUploadFormMessages).html(response);

            $('#addonTitle').val('');
            $('#addonDescription').val('');
            $('#addonFile').val('');
            grecaptcha.reset();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(addonUploadFormMessages).addClass('error');
            grecaptcha.reset();

            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(addonUploadFormMessages).html(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(addonUploadFormMessages).html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in out"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a><strong>Error!</strong> An error occured and your message could not be sent.</div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this line causes the error:

```
xhr: function() {  },
```

without an xhr object you cannot send an ajax request.
So leave out this line.

Also you need to put the "," in at your marked line.
Your url opens because if you leave out the "," the function will throw an error and your e.preventDefault() won't work.

Also I would leave out these lines:

```
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

And you should probably escape the html content in this line:

```
$(addonUploadFormMessages).html(data.responseText);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now im just getting "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in console any ideas also just a note im sending text and files in the request

Comment: and just removing the `xhr: function() {  },` and adding the `,` makes it not send anything at all

Comment: what is `data.responseText`?

Comment: its the data from the ajax requested page if the http code is an error code